# Python - where to exactly use getattr? How is it different from others?

Tags: python

```
li = ['good', 'bad']

li.pop()
getattr(li, "pop")(1)
```

Both of above two operations yield the same results than what exactly the difference between them.

As I've read in docs definition of getattr method, it is mentioned that - You can get reference to a function without knowing it's name until runtime.

But here also we take `'pop'` name of function. What exactly the difference between them?

Please provide me the true usage?

Comment: You wouldn't use `getattr` if you didn't have to (simply because it's longer and harder to read). But if you only have the name of the attribute as a string then you may _have_ to use it.

Answer (score 2):

`getattr()` is not just for `methods`, it can also access `attributes` , Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.a = 10
...
>>> c = CA()
>>> getattr(c,'a')
10
```

Amd `getattr()` is normal used in such cases, when you do not know the attribute to access, until runtime.

So lets assume if the attribute name is coming in as a string from some file or as user input or some other source, the best way to get the attribute value then would be to use the `getattr()` method.

---

For your `pop()` case , as a very simple example (just for educational purposes , you should not use something like this in real code , as it is dangerous) , lets say you want to take the function you want to run (on `l1`) as input from user , the way to run that function would be using `getattr` , Example -

```
>>> li = ['good', 'bad']
>>> funcToRun = input("Which method :
Which method : pop
>>> getattr(li, funcToRun)()
'bad'
```

The above is just one example.

---

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Python can have attributes. For example you have an object `person`, that has several attributes: `name`, `gender`, etc. You access these attributes (be it methods or data objects) usually writing: `person.name`, `person.gender`, `person.the_method()`, etc.

But what if you don't know the attribute's name at the time you write the program? For example you have attribute's name stored in a variable called `gender_attribute_name`.

if

```
attr_name = 'gender'
```

then, instead of writing

```
gender = person.gender
```

you can write

```
gender = getattr(person, attr_name)
```

Some practice:

```
>>> class Person():
...     name = 'Victor'
...     def say(self, what):
...         print(self.name, what)
... 
>>> getattr(Person, 'name')
'Victor'
>>> attr_name = 'name'
>>> person = Person()
>>> getattr(person, attr_name)
'Victor'
>>> getattr(person, 'say')('Hello')
Victor Hello
>>>
```

Also `getattr()` has a 3rd optional parameter which gets sometimes very useful and prevents from silly exceptions. It's like if the `attr` is not present in the `object` it'll then return the 3rd parameter as the value (or default value).

Example:

```
>>> class Person():
...     dob = '04-Aug-1991'
...
>>> getattr(Person, 'dob', '12-Dec-1989')
'04-Aug-1991'
>>> getattr(Person, 'name', 'User')
'User'
```

Answer (score 0):

This function comes in handy when the attribue name is coming from another program, from a user input or is not known in advance.

It is also good to check if the attribute exists or not in a given object.

Granted, your use case is a bit trivial, but imagine if you are dealing with some complex class and you are not sure if it has implemented `some_method_x`, getattr is one way to make sure the attribute exists.

It also has the benefit of being a built-in and like most built-in it works on all objects.